# Angular and Firebase Cloud Functions return null

Tags: angular, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a payment system. I simulate the node.js using cloud functions. I send a request from Angular to Cloud Functions. Then, I send the second request from cloud functions to payment API. Payment API gets the request successfully and payment is successful. But, I guess because of an async structure, the response is shown as null on the Angular side.

Angular Code:

```js
constructor(private fns: AngularFireFunctions) {
}
...

...
const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('app');
var data = callable({req: request})
    
data.subscribe(async res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Cloud functions:

```js
exports.app = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var res = "";
    iyzipay.payment.create(data.req, function (err, result) {
        res = result;
    });
    return res;
});
```

How can I wait for the response? I tried async/await but I don't know these subjects entirely.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After continuing the search, I found a solution like that:

Cloud functions:

```js
exports.app = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return new Promise((Resolve, Reject) => {
        iyzipay.payment.create(data.req, async function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                Reject({
                    id: 'Payment',
                    message: err
                })
            }
            if (result && result.status == 'failure') {
                Reject({
                    id: 'Payment Failed',
                    message: result.errorMessage
                })
            }
            Resolve(result)
        });
    });
});
```

And angular side like Akif said:

```js
    const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('app');
    const res = await callable({ req: request }).toPromise();
    console.log(res);
```